# How to pass java method return value to JavaScript function in JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have the following line in my JSP file:

```
<input type="button" name="btnNew" value="Új" class="button" onClick="clickSubmitButton('newRow'); isRowExists(<%tblMgr.isRowInDueCauseTable(request);%>)">
```

The `isRowInDueCauseTable(request)` method is returning a boolean value, but I'm not sure if I'm passing the boolean value to the javascript `isRowExists` function correctly, because I always get undefined, when I try to evaluate:

```
function isRowExists( isRowInDatabase ) {
        console.log(isRowInDatabase);
        if (isRowInDatabase == true) {
            alert('Already in database');
        }
    }
```

How can I pass the java methods return value to the JavaScript function in JSP?

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax needs the equal character(**=**) to write a value.

See:

Incorrect way:

```
<%tblMgr.isRowInDueCauseTable(request);%>
```

Correct way:

```
<%=tblMgr.isRowInDueCauseTable(request)%>
```

Then:

```
<input type="button" name="btnNew" value="Új" class="button" onClick="clickSubmitButton('newRow'); isRowExists(<%=tblMgr.isRowInDueCauseTable(request)%>)">
```

Answer (score 0):

try AJAX, you can set your text(value to return) to request and then read it in javascript function.